# Proving conservation of heat for the Heat Equation in PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, heat-equation

> For $x\in \mathbb{R}$, let $u(x,t) = (\Gamma_{D} (\cdot , t ) \ast g)(x)$ with $g(x) \ge 0,$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x) dx < \infty$. Prove that for all $t>0$,
> $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x,t) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) dx,$$
> the meaning of this statement is that the total heat is conserved.
> Consider $$E(t) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x,t)dx$$ and show that $E'(t) =0$. You may assume that for any $t>0$, $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} u_{x}(x,t) = \lim\limits_{x\to \infty} u_{x}(x,t) =0$.

#### Attempt at solution

\begin{align}
    E(t) &:=\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x,t) dx\\
    E(t) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi k t}} \exp{\left(\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4kt}\right)}g(y) \ dy\  dx\\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial t}E(t) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(y)  \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi k t}} \exp{\left(\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt}\right)}\right) \ dy\  dx\ \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial t}E(t) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(y) \left( \frac{-1}{4 \sqrt{\pi d t^{3}}} + \frac{(x-y)^{2}}{8\sqrt{\pi d^{3} t^{5}}}\right)\exp{\left(\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt}\right)} \ dy\  dx \ 
\end{align}
I honestly do not know how to proceed from here. I feel like I'm off on the wrong track and that I'm missing something else for this proof.

Comment: It might be easier to just work with the PDE directly instead of invoking the functional form of $u$. Push the derivative inside (you may need to argue why you can do this), then use the PDE to turn it into something else..

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need your boundary condition as $x \to \infty$ to be $\lim_{x \to \infty} u(x, t) \to 0$, not $\lim_{u \to \infty} u(x, t) \to 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plugging in the kernel is not the way to go, just plug in the heat equation itself:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^\infty u\:dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \partial_tu\:dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \partial_x^2u\:dx =0$$

because the integral of a derivative is always zero.

Comment: $+1$ Nice job. Great.

Comment: Thank you , I actually went through this method but I believed it is wrong since their difference is equal to $0$, i.e., $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \partial_{t} u  \ dx - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\partial_{x}^{2} u \ dx = 0$$, how does that show that both are $0$ ? Is one of the integral positive and the other negative such that they both must be equal to $0$ ?

Comment: @hitechphysics one of them is zero so both of them are zero. The integral of a derivative with vanishing end points is always zero.

Comment: What @ninad points out is that you can explicitly compute the integral: $\int_{a}^{b} u_{xx}(x, t)\, dx = u_x(b, t) - u_x(a, t)$. You also know, by assumption, that $u_x \rightarrow 0$ at $\pm\infty$. Let $a \rightarrow -\infty$, $b \rightarrow +\infty$, and you get $dE/dt = 0$.